# Which sans serif and monospace fonts suit Century Schoolbook?

Tags: fonts, typewriter, sans-serif

I find the [Century Schoolbook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century_Type_Family#Century_Schoolbook) family very legible for online documentation. However, I am unsure what [sans serif](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sansseriffonts.html) (for typesetting, e.g., LaTeX package names) and [monospace](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html) (for typesetting code) counterparts to choose for use with this typeface.

Which fonts, in your opinion, could (and could not) be used with Century Schoolbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ironic that you find Century Schoolbook suitable for online documentation, as it was developed nearly 100 years ago for school textbooks!

While googling I found [esperfonto](http://www.esperfonto.com/), which has a search box to help pair fonts.

They [suggest](http://www.esperfonto.com/search.html?typeface=&body=on&sans=on&workswith=Century+Schoolbook) Arial, Helvetica, or Frutiger Humanist 777 for sans fonts.  They don't suggest monospace pairs, though.

The Frutiger family is not free.  I tried Century Schoolbook, Helvetica, and Courier, and it seems to look pretty good.

Here is a sample document (requires `xelatex`) to test your selections:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Font Test}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Century Schoolbook}
\setsansfont{Helvetica}
\setmonofont{Courier}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

This article uses the \textsf{blindtext} package to typeset dummy text.  The preamble is:

\begin{verbatim}
\documentclass{article}
\title{Font Test}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Century Schoolbook}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\setmonofont{Courier}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}
\end{verbatim}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: CentSchbook Mono BT]

There is [a version of Century Schoolbook in monospace](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/century-schoolbook/century-schoolbook-monospaced-10058/specs.html). 
As far as I can tell, it is one of very few monospace typefaces that isn't a slab-e

Answer (score 1):

**Franklin Gothic** is best for sans with **Century Schoolbook** and
**TiredOfCourier** is best for monospace.
This fonts are not free :(
But if you use MS Windows, you already have ITC version of Franklin Gothic.
TiredOfCourier looks like standard Knuth's *Computer Modern Teletype* font.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit the [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to learn about how to get more out of this site.